# Is not awaiting for a promise an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm having an application where I have a function which exectues a task, but that task needs to do follow up, but not related to the task, so shouldn't be awaited. What are the potential dangers/drawbacks of not awaiting for a promise to be fulfilled/rejected?

For example we have an API handler, and we want to log that the user called the endpoint with this and that headers, etc. If I await for that log, the response will be slower with the execution time of the logging.

Comment: If you want a fire and forget *and you're OK with missing an error*, then not awaiting is fine.

Comment: @VLAZ a possible solution for not missing the error is using `.catch()` on the not awaited promise?

Comment: Yes, `doStuff().catch(handleError)` is the normal fire and forget practice.

Comment: `doStuff().then(handleFollowUp)` does not await the promise and therefore won't make the execution a lot slower

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed wait what?

Comment: As in code below that statement will be executed, it does not wait for the promise to resolve